# How would I approach creating a window skin (GDI+, C#)

Tags: c#, game-engine, gdi+

I'm currently creating a GameEngine in C# using GDI+ and am implementing a "MenuComponent" for a 2D style game, but I've come to a point where now I want to my make my menus look nicer, with images behind each button, instead of just text.

However, the issue is that each menu can have different sized text, which in turn means different sized images need to be created for each menu. To me, this sounds tedious and annoying to do this in a 3rd party program (like photoshop, or paint.net) and I'd much rather create a class which will make sure the images will have the right dimensions, but still maintain the same quality no matter the size of the 'control'.

Clearly, there's a better way to approach my issue, but I just don't know how. Like how does RPG Maker allow their windows and buttons to be any size, whilst maintaining the quality of the images, are they making their images on-the-fly?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

If it helps, by menu I mean something like this title screen:
[image]

Comment: The approach I took when making my game using MonoGame was to split  sprite into areas like : _left-border_, _left-top-border_,.., _background_ and then just repeat then when needed. Maybe this will help somewhat.

Comment: Qt uses the same approach as m.rogalski in their [BoarderImage QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-borderimage.html). Seems like the way to go

Comment: @king_nak Thanks for your help guys, I've developed a way to separate the images into 9 bitmaps. But am now having trouble working out how to tile specific bitmaps based on the desired size of the 'control'. Any tips?